# Target value and for loop in R

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

Some data:

```
a <- function(a) {3*a+12*a^2}
dom1 <- seq(-1,4,0.1)
vec1 <- a(dom1)[1:10]

c <- function(c) {-5*c^2+2*c^3}
dom2 <- seq(-0.1,0.2,0.01)
vec2 <- c(dom2)[1:10]

d <- function(d) {2*d^2+5*d^3+12*d^4}
dom3 <- seq(0.1,0.5,0.01)
vec3 <- d(dom3)[1:10]

w <- function(w) {7*w-3*w^2}
dom4 <- seq(0.5,2.5,0.05)
vec4 <- w(dom4)[1:10]
```

Now suppose we fit `lm model` on the larger data set `lm(y~a+c+d+w)` and the lm parameters are `c(-0.2,0.2,0.1,0.6)`

```
fun.mean <- function(a,c,d,w) {-0.2*a+0.2*c+0.1*d+0.6*w}
```

What I tried, but doesn't work as expected:

Here is loop through the vector generated from the relevant function (&domains)

```
for(a in vec1) {
 for(c in vec2) {
  for(d in vec3) {
   for(w in vec4) {
    sol <- fun.mean(a,c,d,w)
    if (sol %% 1 > 0.40 & sol < 0.50) print(c(a,c,d,w))
  }}}}
```

So what I'm looking for is to find combinations of c(a,c,d,w), which equal to 0.5 or ideally would equal to interval `0.4-0.5`.

So multiplying the `c(a,c,d,w)` output with the function `fun.mean` would not give the desired values (interval 0.4-0.5). What I'm doing wrong? Would be there better approach to find the c(a,c,d,w) values given the "target" value? What would be the alternative to `for loop` as it is very slow.

Comment: Maybe you should state exactly what it is you're trying to do and why.

Comment: What do you mean by 'multiplying the output with the function'. What is not working ?

Comment: If you multiply the fun.mean with the each row of the print(c(a,c,d,w) you are not getting values between 0.40 and 0.50

Comment: Maybe it's because of your %% 1, why do you need it ?

Comment: do you mean `apply` instead of `multiply` ?

Comment: No I mean multiply, if you plug the print(c(a,c,d,w)) values back into the fun.mean you won't get values between 0.40-0.50

Comment: if you mean do fun.mean(a,c,d,w) that apply a function not multiplying it ...

Comment: I just mean this, by plunging the values in: 9*(-0.2)-0.052*(0.2)+0.0262*(0.1)+(2.75*0.6)

Comment: @Max  Your responses are not clear.  You need to step back and try to state clearly **what** you want to calculate, not **how** you want to do the calculation.

Comment: @Carl. Thanks. Sure, I will try better next time.

Comment: With your added info about reaching a target value, maybe `optim` or `BB::BBsolve` are what you want to use.

Answer (score 1):

You filter using %%1 but you don't use it when you check the answer.
The following code returns 9.00 -0.052000 0.02620000 2.7500
which gives -0.15778. It matches your criteria (-0.15778 %% 1 = 0.85 which is > 0.4
and -0.15 < 0.5).

I guess your criteria are wrong then, you should probably do either

```
sol %% 1 > 0.4 and sol %% 1 < 0.5
```

or

```
sol > 0.4 and sol < 0.5.
```

In the first case, maybe you should add the %% 1 in fun.mean calculation.

Comment: Please insert your proposition into my loop: if (sol %% 1 > 0.40 & sol %% 1 < 0.50) print(fun.mean(a,c,d,w)) ...and see the output yourself. Something weird is going on :) the values are between 0.40-0.50 but later increase by 1 and 2.

Comment: Yes because of %%1. 2.45 is a valid solution